# How to handle polymer flex layout not being applied due to absolute positioning of that div

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

> HTML

```
<div class="layout horizontal flex around-justified typeArea">
   <input is="iron-input" class="typeBox flex-1" >
   <paper-icon-button icon="polymer" class="pink"></paper-icon-button>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
 .typeArea {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 25px;
                padding: 10px;
            }

   .typeBox {
                padding: 8px;
            }
```

> The flex effects are not visible due to absolute positioning. I need
>   the div at the very bottom.

Comment: Do you really need it to be absolute? I'm guessing the 'flex' property you want to keep is the div one. The flex property of the div won't work with position:absolute because you are overriding the other one. Can you provide a bit more code to it? at least the div's parent to see what can be done

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cold try to use `iron-flex-layout-class` to achieve the absolute positioning.

bower_components\iron-flex-layout\iron-flex-layout-classes.html

```
<dom-module id="iron-positioning">

  /* fixed position */
  .fixed-bottom,
  .fixed-left,
  .fixed-right,
  .fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
  }
```